# Give an example of positive interegers p,a and b where p divides ab ,but p doesnt divide a, and p doesnt divide b.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Give an example of positive integers $p$, $a$, and $b$, where $p$ divides $ab$, but $p$ doesn't divide $a$, and $p$ doesn't divide $b$.

Not sure how to go about this one.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE.  What have you tried?

Comment: Think about the prime factorization of each of the numbers

Comment: A little fooling around will get you plenty of examples. Here is the smallest one: $p=4$, $a=2$, $b=2$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: There is an example with $ab=12$.

Comment: P=4 A=3 B=6 correct?

Comment: @Chandler: I think that you mean to have $p=6$ and $a$ and $b$ as your $3$ and $4$. That works. so does $a=2,b=6$, and $p=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a$ and $b$ any two prime numbers and let $p = ab$. For example, $a = 2$ and $b = 3$, choose $p = 6$. then clearly $p$ does not divide $a$ or $b$, but $p = ab$ so it definitely divides $ab$.

Answer (score 0):

Let 's consider $a =34892384092809482090, b =248902834028$, and let $p = ab = 8684813286693785868871908558520$.  Then $p$ divides $ab$, but neither $a$ or $b$.